# Webhook Connection Override Extensions RFC?

Tags: go, twilio, rfc3986

I'm working with Twilio webhooks for Programmable Voice, writing some simple TwiML responses in a Go API.

Reviewing the [Webhook Connection Overrides](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides) doc, I see a general link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL. Are `URL extensions` a standard HTTP scheme defined within an RFC, or is this a Twilio-specific convention using the `Same Document Reference` as stated in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.4 ?

I'm asking this to properly use `net/http` in Go.

Comment: Yes, url fragments are standard. How does this relate to `net/http`?

Comment: Ill modify my question to explain more correctly.  Twilio takes what looks like query parameters inside the URL fragment and I need to build this server-side.

Comment: No client sends url fragments in a request, these are settings to control their client. There is nothing to do server side.

Answer (score 1):

The [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) `#` in the context of URI's can have multiple use cases. For example, if you enter `http://www.example.org/foo.html#bar` in a web browser, the browser should take you to the position where the CSS id selector of `bar` is located.

In the context of Twilio's webhook requests, anything after the `#` is interpreted as instructions and will not actually be sent to the web server. For example, if you specify `https://example.com/foo?query=123#ct=1000` as your webhook, Twilio will only send `https://example.com/foo?query=123` to the server but will interpret `ct=1000` as the connection having a 1 second Connection Timeout.